# Angular Material - MdInput to MatInputModule?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2

**What I'm Using**

- Angular
- Angular Material ^2.0.0-beta.12

**What I'm doing**

- I just started a new project and installed material
- When copying some syntax from a previous project, I get an error when trying to import

> 'import { MdInputModule} from '@angular/material';

- After digging through the typings, it looks as though it's now changed to 'MatInputModule'
- I've updated my module to use 'MatInputModule'
- Now the HTML throws an error

> 'md-form-field' is not a known element:

- This is using the syntax provided from the material website

**HTML**

```html
<form [formGroup]="albumEdit">
  <md-form-field>
    <input mdInput formControlName="albumTitle" placeholder="Album Title">
  </md-form-field>
</form>
```

**Questions**

1. Am I missing something obvious here?
2. What's the best way to implement the material components in the latest build?
3. Is there some official documentation that I'm missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since `2.0.0-beta.12`, `Md` prefix has been removed in favor of `Mat` prefix. See this [**CHANGELOG**](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#200-beta12-marble-mustache-2017-10-05):

> **Breaking Changes** 
>   All "md" prefixes have been removed.Change `md` prefix to `mat`:

In your typescript,

```
import { MatInputModule} from '@angular/material';
```

and in you template:

```
<mat-form-field>
    <input matInput formControlName="albumTitle" placeholder="Album Title">
</mat-form-field>
```

The documentation on the website is outdated and needs to be update with `mat` prefix.

Comment: Thanks @Faisal for the rapid response! This is great. It removes all errors. However it's now a plain input box, no animations, no highlights, no placeholder etc.  I'm including 'import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations'' in my module.

Comment: Hmm....according to the change log angular needs to be at  4.4.3. I only installed Angular Cli last week. And it's at ^4.2.4.

Comment: upgrade to atleast `4.4.3`

Comment: Silly question, slightly new to this. Is that a case of manually changing the package.json? (Thanks again Faisal)

Comment: You can run `npm update` which will update all the outdated packages - OR - you can manually update the version number of packages you want to update in `package.json` file and then run `npm install` command. I prefer the second way. Also, consider upvoting and accepting the answer :)

Comment: Hi Faisal. I would love to accept the answer, but I still don't have a material input to use. It's just an input, no placeholder animation, or bottom border animation. I've updated all the syntax as suggested.

Comment: You need to include material theme as well. See this demo, it has everything you need ;) https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-mat-beta-11-mj4jym?file=app/app.component.html

Comment: Perfect, starting a project from scratch made me forget the simple bit...) Thanks for your time Faisal. Legend :)

Answer (score 2):

For angular 8+

> import {MatInputModule} from '@angular/material/input';

Comment: For some reason I had to type it all out in VSCode, auto completion seems not to catch it :/

Comment: Yes i had the same auto completion issue

Answer (score 0):

yes, for angular 8 + (versions)
as our colleague Ashu told us. dont forget input at the last sentence.

import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input'

imports [
MatInputModule
]

Thanks Ashu!

pd.
link there...

https://material.angular.io/components/input/api